# Collection view scroll 'jumping' my textView back to the top

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a ViewController with both a horizontal-scroll Container View, and a UITextView (vertical scroll.)

in viewWillLayoutSubViews() I have the following code to set the offset of the textView to the top of the content:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    textViewWithScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```

The problem is if I first scroll the textView down, THEN scroll the collection view, the textView jumps right back to the top. I would like to prevent this jump.

The next closest solution I found is setting the content offset in viewDidAppear. This prevents the scroll "jump" - however when the view first loads, there's a jump from the middle to the top of the textView.

**How can I get the textView to load right at the top of the content, without it jumping back to the top once the collectionView is scrolled?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try implementing a flag logic, forcing the code in viewWillLayoutSubviews to be executed just once, because layouting subviews is something that can happen a hundred times during the life of the view controller. Something like:

```
    private var isTextViewScrolled = false

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

        if !isTextViewScrolled {
            textViewWithScroll.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
            isTextViewScrolled = true
        }
    }
```

// Note: If you experience any problems with it, try moving the code to viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I love this solution. It's elegant, to the point, and simply works! Thank you!! (note - I did in-fact need to add it to viewDidLayoutSubviews).